# Energy dissipation of a resistor in an AC circuit

Tags: voltage, power, resistors, ac, energy

I am given a resistor of known resistance with a sinusoidal voltage across it, and am asked to calculate the energy dissipation between t=0 and t=1.
Not sure how to do it. Would I

1. Use P=V^2/R and integrate between the limits to calculate energy dissipation

or

2. Calculate voltage at t=0 and t=1, then use P=V^2/R?

Thank you for your response.

Comment: Option 1 because \$ Enegy = \int P dt \$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Calculate voltage at t=0 and t=1, then use P=V^2/R?

Nope, power (or voltage) at t=0 and t=1 gives no information about what happens between t=0 and t=1.

> Use P=V^2/R and integrate between the limits to calculate energy dissipation

Yes, you have to calculate

\$ Energy = \int_{t=t_0}^{t=t_1} power dt = \frac{1}{R} \int_{t=t_0}^{t=t_1} v^2 dt\$

Also \$ P_{avg} = \frac{Energy}{t_1-t_0} = \frac{1}{t_1-t_0} \int_{t=t_0}^{t=t_1} \frac{v^2}{R} dt = \frac{1}{t_1-t_0} \frac{1}{R} \int_{t=t_0}^{t=t_1} v^2 dt\$

\$ P_{avg} = V_{rms}^2/R\$ with Vrms being the RMS (root mean square) value of voltage.

\$ V_{rms} = \sqrt{ \frac{1}{t_1-t_0} \int_{t=t_0}^{t=t_1} v^2 dt }\$

If you combine these two equations you will end up with the one on top using average power.

When an AC voltage (or any periodic voltage) is considered, its "RMS voltage" is the DC voltage that would result in the same dissipation in a resistor.